# Django forms raise general validation error if all fields empty

Tags: django, forms

I have a form where none of the fields are required indivdually, but I want to raise a validation error if all fields are left empty. What is the best way to do this? I tried the following but it it didn't work:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SearchForm, self).clean()
    if len(cleaned_data) == 0:
        raise forms.ValidationError(ugettext_lazy("You must fill at least one field!"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than checking the length of the `cleaned_data` (it should always contain one entry for each form field), you should check each entry and confirm that the values are all empty.

Here's an example of how you could do it.

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(SearchForm, self).clean()
    form_empty = True
    for field_value in cleaned_data.itervalues():
        # Check for None or '', so IntegerFields with 0 or similar things don't seem empty.
        if field_value is not None and field_value != '':
            form_empty = False
            break
    if form_empty:
        raise forms.ValidationError(ugettext_lazy("You must fill at least one field!"))
    return cleaned_data   # Important that clean should return cleaned_data!
```

Comment: I agree with this answer, but do be careful you're testing for the right thing when you check to see if a field is "empty".  A string field that is empty will be "", not None.  But an integer field that is empty should probably be None, because 0 may be a valid input.  In the latter case, if you use "is" or "is not" to tell if the field is empty or not, you will generate a false positive on 0.

Comment: @AndrewG. yes, important to make sure that it is actually empty.   You also need to watch out for `BooleanField`s that have been set as `False`.

Comment: @AndrewG. I think you mean you create a false positive if you do `if not integer_field: # empty`. Using `is None` or `== None` works fine.

Comment: @agf Yes, `is None` will work -- but it won't work for strings, because they will be "" and not None.  So you can't use `is None` for all fields without considering what the proper empty value is.

Comment: Added some example code since there was apparently some confusion here.  Hope that helps.

Comment: `form_empty` should be false if **all** fields are `None` or `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore fields filled with just whitespace as well: `and not field_value.isspace()`